# Why identical particle states are multiplied?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, identical-particles

In case of identical particles we multiply the individual wave functions of the particles to get the system wave funtion. But why are we not adding? Or performing any other operation to get the system wave function. Can anyone show the math that what physics will be violated if i simply add the individual particle's wave function?

Comment: The question is not clear. When you say "multiply" are you referring to notation like this: $\left \lvert \Psi \right \rangle \left \lvert \Phi \right \rangle$? If so, that's not really multiplication in the usual sense. It's really just concatenation of the states of each subsystem. Also, this is used whether or not the particles are identical. Please clarify the question.

Comment: I do mean that... A product of two states and ignoring entanglement

Comment: But my question is why do we take it to be this way? And not just add the two states?

Comment: That is because they are identical, since they are identical you cannot label particle 1 with $\psi _a$ and particle 2 with $\psi _b$ so we take the linear combination of $\psi_a \psi_b$

Comment: Addition means something very particular. If you have a spin in a superposition of up and down you use a sum $|\uparrow \rangle + |\downarrow \rangle$. Having multiple particles is a totally different thing. You can have two spins in a superposition state $|\uparrow\rangle|\downarrow \rangle + |\downarrow\rangle |\uparrow \rangle$, so there's a sum and a "product".

Comment: If we have spinless particles, does this still hold?

Comment: each particle lives in its own hilbert space, it does not make any sense to add them (just imagine if the particles were not identical)

Comment: @DanielSank - I assure you that what you call "concatenation" *is* a totally standard multiplication. It's "tensor multiplication" which sounds complicated but what it really means is that all the products of any component from the first and any component of the second are remembered by the "concatenation" (no summation, like in the inner or cross product).

Comment: @LubošMotl I know what tensor multiplication is and how it works, but explaining why tensor multiplication makes sense for quantum states seems unnecessarily complex given what I guess to be OP's current level. Also, I always feel a bit dirty explaining tensors by inspecting their components. I like your answer though.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel, but it's hard to see how you can avoid the fact that the components are "multiplied" in this operation - if you want your statement about the symbols not to be *entirely* vacuous. You may call $\psi\phi$ a "concatenation", in the sense of addition of strings in linguistics, but $\psi+\phi$ is a "concatenation" of a sort as well, isn't it? You may say that certain things are "too complex" but if you don't distinguish multiplication from addition, you should better not talk about the numbers (or wave functions) at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wave function for *any* composite system consisting of two uncorrelated (unentangled) subsystems is the (tensor) product 
$$ |\psi_A\rangle |\psi_B\rangle \equiv |\psi_A\rangle \otimes |\psi_B\rangle  $$
This multiplicative behavior of states isn't a specific feature of identical particles – or any particles. It holds for any physical system that may be divided to two (or several) parts.

The reason why the "combination" of several particles or objects is given by the multiplication and not addition is that the numerical values of wave functions in quantum mechanics don't represent "properties of objects" themselves but the probabilities (probability amplitudes, more precisely) of different properties of the objects.

We have the Born rule that says e.g.
$$ \rho (x) = |\psi(x)|^2 $$
The probability or probability density is given by the squared absolute value of some value of the wave function (or a linear combination of these values).

If we describe properties of objects $A,B$ that are independent, they may have various probabilities. The probability that the system $A$ has the $i$-th property is $P_{A,i}$. The probability that $B$ has the $j$-th property is $P_{B,j}$. If the objects $A,B$ are independent of each other, the probability that $A$ has the $i$-th property and $B$ has the $j$-th property is the product of probabilities
$$ P_{AB,ij} = P_{A,i} P_{B,j} $$
This is the usual multiplicative rule for probabilities of independent things. For example, if die $A$ has $P=1/6$ to land as 6 and $B$ has $1/6$ to land as $6$, the probability that we get $6+6$ is $1/6\times 1/6 = 1/36$.

The multiplicative formula for the wave functions $\psi_A$ and $\psi_B$ is basically just a "square root" of the formula for the probabilities. The calculus of the wave functions must reproduce and does reproduce some rules from the probability calculus – because the probabilities are linked to the wave functions by the relatively simple rule.

In particular, all Hilbert spaces of allowed states of composite systems $A+B$ are unavoidably given by tensor products ${\mathcal H}_A \otimes {\mathcal H}_B$ and unentangled states of two particles are tensor products of the two pure states.

The addition is something completely different. The state
$$|\uparrow\rangle + |\downarrow\rangle $$
describes a particle whose spin (that's what my arrow referred to) is *either* up *or* down. The addition translates to the word "or", not the word "and", because the addition of the wave functions is sort of analogous to the addition of probabilities, and the probability of "U or V" is
$$ P(U\text{ or }V) = P(U) + P(V) - P(U\text{ and } V) $$
If $U,V$ are mutually exclusive, the last term is zero. But we still see that "or" refers to the addition of probabilities, and a similar statement about the wave function says that their sums refer to "either one term" or "the other terms". Except that the relative phase between the complex probability amplitudes also matters in quantum mechanics – while the classical probabilities never come with any phases.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

Imagine that the state vectors are represented by real-space wave functions.  For any particular value of the possible location of particle A, the entire space of values for B are available for the position of B.   For another location of A, again, the entire space is available for B.

In order to account for all possible combinations of the location of A and B, one multiplies the probability amplitude for finding the particles in their respective locations.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify things--it's just what you do with probabilities.
Consider 2 non interacting particles uniformly distributed in a box of length 1. Their wave functions are:

$ \psi_1(x) = \Pi(x_1) $

$ \psi_2(x) = \Pi(x_2) $

where $\Pi$ is the unit box function equal to 1 on [0, 1] and 0 elsewhere. If we were to add probabilities (or amplitudes), the probability that both particles are in the box is 2. (Unitarity anyone?). If we multiple probabilities, the it is 1--they are in the box.